# Calling a function through pointer to an array of function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to understand the syntax to call the function through a pointer to an array of function pointers. 
I have array of function pointers `FPTR arr[2]`, and a pointer to this array `FPTR (vptr)[2]` . But it gives me an error when trying to call through the pointer to an array

```
typedef int (*FPTR)();
int func1(){
        cout<<"func1() being called\n";
}
int func2(){
        cout<<"fun2() being called\n";
}

    FPTR arr[2] = {&func1,&func2};

    FPTR (*vptr)[2];
    vptr=&arr;

    cout<<"\n"<<vptr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"\n"<<vptr[0]()<<endl;  // ERROR  when trying to call the first function
```

Comment: `vptr` is pointer, so first you should dereference it before accesing elements of array pointed to by it:  `(*vptr)[0]()`.

Comment: I had tried that but i couldn't understand why `(*vptr)[0]` prints 1 always no matter for `[0]` or `[1]` or any other element of an array. Sameways, `cout<<func1` or `cout<<&func1` also prints 1 always

Comment: If you want to print pointer you need to cast to `void*` otherwise `ostream::operator<<(bool)` is called.  `cout<<"\n"<< (void*)(*vptr)[0]<<endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
typedef int (*FPTR)();
int func1(){
        cout<<"func1() being called\n";
        return 1;

}
int func2(){
        cout<<"fun2() being called\n";
        return 2;
}

FPTR arr[2] = {func1, func2}; 

// call both methods via array of pointers
cout<<"\n"<< arr[0]() <<endl;
cout<<"\n"<< arr[1]() <<endl;

FPTR (*vptr)[2] = &arr;

// call both methods via pointer to array of pointers
cout<<"\n"<< vptr[0][0]() <<endl;
cout<<"\n"<< vptr[0][1]() <<endl;

// or... 
cout<<"\n"<< (*vptr)[0]() <<endl;
cout<<"\n"<< (*vptr)[1]() <<endl;
```

Comment: Note that `func1` and `func2` does not return any value so `cout << (*vptr)[0]()` will cause undefined behavior

Answer (score 5):

`vptr` is *pointer* to an array, so you must dereference it to use the array.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef int (*FPTR)();
int func1(){
        cout<<"func1() being called\n";
        return 0;
}
int func2(){
        cout<<"fun2() being called\n";
        return 2;
}

int main(){
    FPTR arr[2] = {&func1,&func2};

    FPTR (*vptr)[2];
    vptr=&arr;

    cout<<"\n"<<vptr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"\n"<<(*vptr)[0]()<<endl;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24f6aa02ddcf5ba5)

Note that `func1()` and `func2()` must return value, or outputting their results would cause undefined behavior

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to an array is not needed here. A pointer to the first array element works.

```
FPTR *vptr;
vptr = arr;

// vptr[0]() works
```

A reference to an array is also ok.

```
FPTR (&vptr)[2] = arr;

// vptr[0]() still works
```

If for some reason you need a pointer to an array, you can:

```
FPTR (*vptr)[2];
vptr = arr;

// (*vptr)[0]() works
```

To avoid confusion, prefer `std::array` to plain arrays.